# FireBird CodeIgniter multiple database connection

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, firebird

Noob in PHP interbase.

i'm working on a project where i need to save the data in 2 separate databases.
i use default MySQL database while another one using firebird.
downloaded [this library](https://github.com/cgarciagl/Firebird-for-Codeigniter)

here's my database.php in config folder.

```
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "po_pusat";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";  

$db['sdisdb']['hostname'] = "myIp";
$db['sdisdb']['username'] = "sysdba";
$db['sdisdb']['password'] = "masterkey";    
$db['sdisdb']['database'] = "D:\path\to\database.fdb";
$db['sdisdb']['dbdriver'] = "firebird";
$db['sdisdb']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['sdisdb']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['sdisdb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['sdisdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['sdisdb']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['sdisdb']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['sdisdb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

the function that require multiple database

```
          function save()
            {

/*.....*/
            $order= true;
        $this->item_model->create_purchaseorder($data['companyid'],$data['username'],$status,$data['tanggal'],$data['reqdate'],$data['duedate']);                   $data['purchaseorderid']=$this->item_model->get_purchaseorderid();
    $this->item_model->create_purchaseorderdb2($data['companyid'],$data['username'],$status,$data['tanggal'],$data['purchaseorderid'],$data['duedate']);

            }
```

the model

```
function create_purchaseorderdb2($company,$username,$status,$tanggal,$purchaseorderid,$duedate){

        $this->db2=$this->load->database('sdisdb',TRUE);


        $data= array(
        'SOHEADERID'                => '',
        'COMPANYID'             => $company,
        'ECCODE'                => 'IDR',
        'STATUS'                => $status,
        'SODATE'                => $tanggal,
        'WEBSOHEADERID'             => $purchaseorderid
        );

        $this->db2->insert('SOHEADER',$data);
    }
```

i have no problem with the create_purchaseorder function
but when i run the "save" function it gives me this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect()

i already modified the php.ini file
;extension=php_interbase.dll to extension=php_interbase.dll

Comment: Do you actually have a `php_interbase.dll` in your PHP install?

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have php_interbase.dll in your PHP install. For reference:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php